# VBA - Adding to an existing formula

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I have various formulas in a spreadhseet that I need to convert to a different unit of measure.

Some are as simple a value such as 889 and others are a formula such as the below;

```
=Incision_Point_1x+(Arm_Depth_1-Graphic_Radius)
```

I'd like to use VBA to quickly take the existing formula / value and convert it to;

```
=(889/Unit_of_Measure_Multiplier)
=(Incision_Point_1x+(Arm_Depth_1-Graphic_Radius)/Unit_of_Measure_Multiplier)
```

How can I do this?

I used the following code;

```
Range("B3") = "=(" & Range("B3") & "/" & "Unit_Of_Measure_Multiplier)"
```

Which works perfectly when you have a whole number but deletes the formula and replaces it with a value for my second example, which defeats the point.

Additionally, how do I then apply this to a large data range?  i.e. apply it to range B3:D100?

Comment: So, do you try replacing of `(Incision_Point_1x+(Arm_Depth_1-Graphic_Radius)` with 889? Should this understanding be correct?

Comment: Still alive? Do you really need help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub test1()
    For Each cl In Range("B3:D100")
        If cl.HasFormula Then
            v = Mid(cl.Formula, 2)  'remove leading =
        Else
            v = cl.Value
        End If
        frm = "=(" & v & "/Unit_Of_Measure_Multiplier)"
        Debug.Print frm 'check that this is what you want
        cl.Formula = frm
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly, but I had to modify slightly;
frm = "=(" & v & ")/Unit_Of_Measure_Multiplier"

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub adaptFormula()
  Dim rngFormula As Range, cel As Range
  On Error Resume Next 'for the case of no formula in the range...
   Set rngFormula = Range("B3:D100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If rngFormula Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  For Each cel In rngFormula.cells 'iterate only between cells having a formula
        If InStr(cel.Formula, "=(Inc") > 0 Then
            cel.Formula = Replace(cel.Formula, "Incision_Point_1x+(Arm_Depth_1-Graphic_Radius)", "889")
        End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Please, check if `"Incision_Point_1x+(Arm_Depth_1-Graphic_Radius)"` as you show us, is not `"Incision_Point_1x + (Arm_Depth_1-Graphic_Radius"` (spaces in front and after "+"), as it looks to me more probably. If so, please adapt the string to be replaced according to your real formula string...